# How could get assertion Id from saml response, in devise-saml-authentication model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, saml

I am using devise-saml-authentication gem, now I need to save assertion id from saml response to user column. How could I get saml assertion Id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the received SAMLResponse and get ID from Assertion element.

Example Assertion ID:

```
<saml:Assertion ID="_d71a3a8e9fcc45c9e9d248ef7049393fc8f04e5f75" ...>
```